HTML form action - Login Page Validation in Django
I've a login page which takes Username, Email ID and Password.
I check if these values are matching with database data in views.py file. If those three values are correct, that means, user already exists and user wants to see the homepage.
If entered values are not matching, that means, user does not exist, and want to show an error message "User does not exist, please signup", in the same html page.
I've done the verification part in views.py.
But when I click on Submit button on Login page, even if the user doesn't exist, it's going to Homepage.
Login.html
<body>
<div class = "tablediv">
    <div><h1>LOGIN FORM</h1></div>
    {% if message != "verification successfull!" %}
        <p class = "error">{{ message }}</p>
        <form action="" method="POST">
    {% else %}
        <form action="{% url 'helloworld' %}" method="POST">
    {% endif %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <label for = "name"><b>Username</b></label><br>
            <input type = "text" id = "name" placeholder = "Enter username here" name = "username" required> 
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <label for = "mail"><b>Email ID</b></label><br>
            <input type = "email" id ="mail" placeholder=" Enter mail id here" name = "email">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <label for = "pass" maxlength = "10" ><b>Password</b></label><br>
            <input type = "password" id = "pass" name = "password" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>   
            <input type = "checkbox" id = "remember" checked>
            <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "LOGIN">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="container" >
    <!-- <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>s -->
    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
</div>

Views.py
def Login(request):
username = ''
passwd = ''
email = ''
signupform = SignUPform(request.POST)
print(request.method)
dbprint = list(SignUPdb.objects.all().values())
print(dbprint)
for i in dbprint:
    i.pop('id')
print(dbprint)
message = ""
if request.method == "POST" and signupform.is_valid():
    print("inside POST")
    username = signupform.cleaned_data['username']
    email = signupform.cleaned_data['email']
    passwd = signupform.cleaned_data['password']
    newdict = {
        'username' : username,
        'email' : email,
        'password' : passwd
    }
    print(newdict)
    if newdict in dbprint:
        message = "verification successfull!"
        print(message)
    else:
        message = "user not found. please signup to proceed."
        print(message)
return render(request, "login.html", {'message' : message })

def Home(request):
return HttpResponse("Hello World <3 !!")

Urls.py
urlpatterns = [
path('addtodb/', FormPage, name = 'addtodb'),
path('helloworld/', Home, name = 'helloworld'),]

form.html
<form action = "/form/" method = "POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
<input id="your_name" type="text" name="name" REQUIRED>
<input type="submit" value= ok ><br>


What is print(newdict) printing and what do you have inside dbprint? (you may change your actual values if they are secrets, but make sure that you are consistent, that is, you change the same value to the same thing in all its occurrences)

i'm converting the values entered by the user to a dictionary. that's newdict. taking values from form and convert it a new dictionary and check that dictionary is present in the database.

I do see your code. I asked for the actual values.

I hope you're asking the newdict values.
let it be.
}```
These can be random values. but to login sussessfully, what ever user enters in login form, it has to be there in database.

My initial question was very clear. I asked for newdict's values (which you now provided) as well as for dbprint values.

oops my bad. sorry.
i've a signup page. So whatever user enters in signup form, it'll get saved in database. (dbprint) So in Login form, i'll check these newdict dictionary values are there in database (dbprint).
Means the values can be anything. Its Users choice.
for example, database has only one user credentials.
dbprint = [{'name' : 'Krishna', 'email' : 'krishna@gmail.com', 'password' :'krishna@123', }]. Since it matches with the newdict dictionary, that user should see the next home page when he/she click on submit.
I hope this is clear.

In the question you have said "But when I click on Submit button on Login page, even if the user doesn't exist, it's going to Homepage." so the problem seems to be that login succeeds even if there was no matching user. Your newdict was found among the users, so it's not reproducing the issue you have mentioned in the question. If you change your input to something else, which does not exist in the database, then what happens?

If you see the views.py, Login function, there's a check (if newdict in dbprint:)if that pair of user credentials (newdict) is present in database (dbprint). If i'm giving a wrong credentials which are not in dbprint, i'm able to see the output is correct in the terminal. But since form action is set to the next page, it's getting redirected to that page even if the user doesn't exist. I think I need to change something in html page.

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't seem to find the part which redirects to homepage and the condition for the redirection. Can you point out where is that happening in the code that you have shared? If you have not shared it yet, can you edit your question and share that part of the code?

I'm using a if loop in html body. <form action="{% url 'addtodb' %}" method="POST"> I don't know if this the correct way to do it.
expecting if user exist, it'll redirect to addtodb page. will not redirect and stays in same html login page with an error if user dosen't exist.

Isn't addtodb supposed to add the user? Is it also the homepage?

I just gave a redirection page. what it does doesn't really matter here, right. ? If yes, I can give some other page.

You are specifying the form action before the login attempt happens. Since before the first attempt you are not having a message yet, it will always fall back to the else at the first display. Once you submit your form, the authdb is being displayed and whatever it does - which was not shown in the question - will happen.

Can you please help me on what change i need to make here? I'm just learning Django.

You first need to show addtodb

I made a little change in my question. Now if user exist I want to display 'hellowold' page. that page displays a single text Hello World <3!!

You Should Handled the Naviagtor to the Function not in the html.
Here the code for View.py
def Login(request):
username = ''
passwd = ''
email = ''
signupform = SignUPform(request.POST)
print(request.method)
dbprint = list(SignUPdb.objects.all().values())
print(dbprint)
for i in dbprint:
    i.pop('id')
print(dbprint)
message = ""
if request.method == "POST" and signupform.is_valid():
    print("inside POST")
    username = signupform.cleaned_data['username']
    email = signupform.cleaned_data['email']
    passwd = signupform.cleaned_data['password']
    newdict = {
        'username' : username,
        'email' : email,
        'password' : passwd
    }
    print(newdict)
    if newdict in dbprint:
        message = "verification successfull!"
        print(message)
        return redirect('helloworld') // add this logic
    else:
        message = "user not found. please signup to proceed."
        print(message)
    return render(request, "login.html", {'message' : message })

def Home(request):
return HttpResponse("Hello World <3 !!")

And You should also improve your html code.
The html code goes like this:
<body>
<div class = "tablediv">
    <div><h1>LOGIN FORM</h1></div>
{% if message %}
    <p class="error">{{ message }}</p>
{% endif %} 
    <form action="{% url 'helloworld' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <label for = "name"><b>Username</b></label><br>
            <input type = "text" id = "name" placeholder = "Enter username here" name = "username" required> 
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <label for = "mail"><b>Email ID</b></label><br>
            <input type = "email" id ="mail" placeholder=" Enter mail id here" name = "email">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <label for = "pass" maxlength = "10" ><b>Password</b></label><br>
            <input type = "password" id = "pass" name = "password" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>   
            <input type = "checkbox" id = "remember" checked>
            <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "LOGIN">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="container" >
    <!-- <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>s -->
    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
</div> 


To handle user login correctly and display an error message when the user does not exist.

Update the HTML Form: Make sure the form always sends data to the login view and can show error messages when needed.

Update the views.py File:Adjust the login view to verify user details using Django's ORM for accurate validation.



What change should I make to go to a new page, if user exists. or get an error message if user doesn't exist in the same html form.
